# Haskell remote file IO library (like kio)?

Tags: haskell, file-io

Is there a remote file IO library for Haskell? In KDE, for example, the kio subsystem provides a URL-style interface for accessing files, so most KDE applications could open a remote file via SFTP as easily as a local one. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, writes are part of the problem... and I am particularly interested in SFTP / SSH. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that provides a unified file-esque interface based on URLs, although you could technically hack one up with GHC's support for defining custom types of `Handle`s (as used in [knob](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/knob)).

But you can process streaming data from various sources in a consistent way with iteratee-style packages like [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) and [enumerator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator). For instance, there are conduit interfaces to [files](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/latest/doc/html/Data-Conduit-Binary.html#v%3asourceFile), [HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) (IMO the best HTTP interface for Haskell even when not using conduits directly), [FTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ftp-conduit), [raw network sockets](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-conduit), and so on. IMO, these are better-suited to processing data from multiple sources than a `Handle`-style file IO solution; things like seeking make no sense in the context of a sequential network stream.

Of course, these don't solve the problem of providing a consistent user interface to all of these; some additional work will be required. The simplest route is probably to process [`URI`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/latest/doc/html/Network-URI.html) from the standard network package, mapping them to `Source`s (or equivalent) appropriately. For things like files and HTTP, it should be as simple as processing the protocol and passing the rest of the URI as a string to the appropriate library.

In summary: No, but all the necessary pieces to processing local and remote data in a unified manner like this are present, and the user interface part shouldn't be overly difficult to write if you need it.